# PHPunit - CLI PHP file includes/requires

Tags: php, phpunit

For example if I have a php script called "RunAllTests.php" in '/var/www/tests/RunAllTests.php' and I execute phpunit within the that directory, the includes in "RunAllTests.php" are found.

If I execute phpunit on that same file, from another directory, lets say '/var/www/', the included files in "RunAllTests.php" cannot be located. - "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in"

I kept this a little bit vague, let me know if you need some more specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requires are wrong / not portable: they expect the directory of the file (or some other fixed directory) to be the working dir.

Your options are:

1. Just start the process from the correct dir.
2. `chdir(__DIR__)` in your script.
3. include / require relative to the `__DIR__` constant in your files (which IMHO is most portable)
4. define a working dir in code beforehand, use that value (related to (3) but more fixed).

Comment: Thanks wrikken.  Ended up using chdir since some of the includes are relative paths 1 directory back which was making the magicvar __DIR__ not applicable I believe... still learning.

Comment: Well, you can still `include __DIR__.'/../levelhigherfile.php';`

Comment: You can put the value of `__DIR__` in a constant `APPLICATION_PATH` or `TEST_PATH` and use that constant in your other files.

Comment: ...which is what I meant with point (4), sorry if that wasn't clear.